# How do I implement Google places autocomplete on a search widget in my android app?

Tags: java, android, search, android-activity, google-places-api

I'm pretty new to android development, and I've been making an app and following along on the developer documentation. I am trying to integrate google places api with the autocomplete feature into my app. Basically, I have integrated my map fragment and my search widget. I'm stuck on trying to integrate the code to provide a list of places every time a letter is inputted.

index.java

```
package com.connortlee.justspace;

import android.app.Activity;


import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class index extends Activity implements LocationListener,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    protected LatLng currentLocation;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));



        //google map and location services

        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 100, 1000, this);
        } else {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 100, 1000, this);
        }

    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        final SearchView stop = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            stop.clearFocus();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    private void getLocationClient() {
        if (locationClient == null) {
            locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        if (servicesConnected()) {
            getLocationClient();
            locationClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        locationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        currentLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLocation, 15);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d("Latitude", "status");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.d("Latitude", "enable");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Log.d("Latitude", "disable");
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.index, menu);

        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */

    public boolean servicesConnected() {
        int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (errorCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Display the connection status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
     * Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry. Location services not available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


}
```

searchableActivity.java

```
package com.connortlee.justspace;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class SearchableActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "locationAlarm";

    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyAjtXXyZsECNNewDVAHKiN4QHIEZLWvW3g";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);

        // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doMySearch(query);

        }
    }

    private void doMySearch(String query) {

        Log.d("Event", query);
    }


}
```

I'm still pretty new to android development so pointers in the right direction would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I am still trying to figure this out. I believe I need a content provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windwaker's library looks great for the Java side.  If you would like to try a library that provides a `GooglePlaceAutoComplete` widget for Android, you could take a look at [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) (I'm the developer).

After the library is configured with your Google API key, you can add a [GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html) element to your layout.  For example:

```
<net.sf.sprockets.widget.GooglePlaceAutoComplete
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And then you can get the [Place](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/google/Place.Prediction.html) that a user selects by setting an [OnPlaceClickListener](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.OnPlaceClickListener.html).

```
public void onPlaceClick(AdapterView<?> parent, Prediction place, int position) {
    /* do something with the Place */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually created a library in Java for this very purpose. It's basically a wrapper around Google Places API and is feature-complete. In order to use the library you must have a Google Places API key. ([instructions](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#Authentication))

You can receive autocomplete predictions with the library like so:

```
GooglePlaces client = new GooglePlaces("YOUR_API_KEY_HERE");
List<Place> places = client.getQueryPredictions(query);
```

or by place name with:

```
List<Place> places = client.getPlacePrediction(placeName);
```

Make sure you don't perform these on the main thread!

[Library on GitHub](https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java)

[Documentation](https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java/blob/master/README.md)

Hope this helps!